# Determining the best starter in Pokemon Red?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

How do I tell which is the best starter in Pokemon Red? I'm doing a roguelike run where if a Pokemon is killed it is dead forever and I want to have a good fighter and don't want to lose it right off the bat.

Comment: Your post was incorrectly tagged, so retagging it will help it get more attention. Asking people not to downvote is not a good idea (and will probably just get you downvotes).

Comment: @user114609 - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: Is this just a permadeath run or are you playing by the "only catch the first pokemon" Nuzlocke rule too?

Answer (score 4):

This is really a matter of preference.

Bulbasaur is the "easiest" pick, as he will be super effective against the first two gyms (his Grass typing is strong against Brock's rock types and Misty's water types), but less effective against later gyms. Squirtle will be super effective against Brock, but not again until Blaine. Charmander has a disadvantage against Brock and Misty, but eventually has advantages against Erica.

Really, pick whichever one you think looks coolest. Pokemon is not designed to be an overly challenging game. Along the way you are able to catch and train many other pokemon to compliment your starter. I personally prefer Bulbasaur, but there is no wrong choice.